# 100.0%sy with poor disk performance

Tags: performance, io, top

I have RHEL 5.4 kernel 2.6.18-164.el5 and I am experiencing very bad disk performance that happens randomly during working with Oracle.

Nothing appears in the logs.

When it happens, I see one CPU core stuck at 100% system time in `top`:

```
Cpu0  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  :  1.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :  1.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu4  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu5  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu6  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu7  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu8  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu9  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu10 :  0.0%us,100.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu11 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu12 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu13 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu14 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu15 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8097368k total,  5761028k used,  2336340k free,   602024k buffers
Swap:  2088440k total,        0k used,  2088440k free,  3070188k cached
```

Checking disk writes with `dd` I get same on top and it shows:

```
time dd if=/dev/zero of=1000 bs=2M count=500 conv=fdatasync

79+0 records in
79+0 records out
165675008 bytes (166 MB) copied, 279.746 seconds, 592 kB/s

real    4m40.565s
user    0m0.000s
sys 4m40.521s 

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
8557 root      25   0 65212 2640 2548 R 99.8  0.0   3:02.99 dd
```

During normal operations I get:

```
500+0 records in
500+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 9.24778 seconds, 113 MB/s

real    0m9.249s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m1.772s
```

The disks are two 15k RPM SAS in a RAID1 configuration managed by a MegaRAID SAS9261-8i controller.

I have already upgraded both the driver and the firmware of the controller.

The strange problem is that the system can work fine for weeks and all disk benchmarks show good results.

How can this poor disk performance be debugged?

for Patrick request this is the output during 100%sy

```
top - 14:12:57 up 13 days, 15:49,  3 users,  load average: 1.28, 1.48, 1.17
Tasks: 424 total,   2 running, 422 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu0  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu4  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu5  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu6  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu7  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu8  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu9  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu10 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu11 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu12 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu13 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu14 :  0.0%us,100.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu15 :  0.0%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8097368k total,  6167440k used,  1929928k free,   306644k buffers
Swap:  2088440k total,        4k used,  2088436k free,  3638216k cached
```

mpstat -P ALL 3 1

```
02:13:19 PM  CPU   %user   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal   %idle    intr/s
02:13:22 PM  all    0.06    0.00    6.50    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00   93.42   1077.00
02:13:22 PM    0    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00   1001.33
02:13:22 PM    1    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
02:13:22 PM    2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.33    0.00    0.00   99.67     43.67
02:13:22 PM    3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
02:13:22 PM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.33    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.67     16.33
02:13:22 PM    5    0.33    0.00    2.99    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.68      0.00
02:13:22 PM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.33
02:13:22 PM    7    0.33    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.67      0.00
02:13:22 PM    8    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
02:13:22 PM    9    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
02:13:22 PM   10    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
02:13:22 PM   11    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
02:13:22 PM   12    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
02:13:22 PM   13    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
02:13:22 PM   14    0.00    0.00  100.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     14.33
02:13:22 PM   15    0.66    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.34      0.00

Average:     CPU   %user   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal   %idle    intr/s
Average:     all    0.06    0.00    6.50    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00   93.42   1077.00
Average:       0    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00   1001.33
Average:       1    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
Average:       2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.33    0.00    0.00   99.67     43.67
Average:       3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
Average:       4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.33    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.67     16.33
Average:       5    0.33    0.00    2.99    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.68      0.00
Average:       6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.33
Average:       7    0.33    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.67      0.00
Average:       8    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
Average:       9    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
Average:      10    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
Average:      11    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
Average:      12    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
Average:      13    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
Average:      14    0.00    0.00  100.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     14.33
Average:      15    0.66    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.34      0.00
```

sar -I XALL 3 1
interrupts higher than 0

```
Average:         INTR    intr/s
Average:            0   1000.33
Average:           51      7.33
Average:           59      1.00
Average:           75     23.33
Average:          218     61.67
Average:          233      0.33
```

it seems not interrupts issue

Comment: 2.6.18 is an *ancient* kernel ( it was released in 2006! ).  You really should upgrade.

Comment: @psusi Given the user running RHEL and Oracle that may not be an option...

Comment: @psusi redhat backports critical fixes to older kernels. It may be 2.6.18, but its still up to date with fixes. The only thing missing vs newer kernels would be features.

Comment: redhat ports some features as well

Comment: I deleted my answer as its obviously incorrect based on the info you provided. This shows that its not interrupts or anything, but really is the kernel consuming all the CPU time. I cannot think of why this would be. The only thing I can think of is something wrong with the filesystem (and so filesystem driver is eating CPU). You might also try upgrading to one of the later RHEL5 point releases (5.7 is the latest).

Comment: The filesystem isnt mounted with `sync` turned on is it?

Comment: yes it without it / ext3 defaults 1 1

Comment: Thats whats in fstab, what does `mount` say?

Comment: @Patrick /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 on / type ext3 (rw)

Comment: ya, i'm clueless. something is causing the kernel to spend way too long during write() operations it seems. I would open an offical support ticket with redhat at this point.

Comment: yes that what we did. i will update here with the progress

Comment: @Patrick we found the problem vm.zone_reclaim_mode was set by default to 1 we disabled it by sysctl vm.zone_reclaim_mode=0 and its not happened again

Comment: Thanks. Wasnt familiar with that VM setting. Will definitely keep it noted.

Answer (score 3):

We found the problem. `vm.zone_reclaim_mode` was set to 1 by default.

We disabled it by sysctl `vm.zone_reclaim_mode=0` and it has not happened again. There are several places with info about it:

- http://blog.fastmail.fm/2010/09/15/default-zone_reclaim_mode-1-on-numa-kernel-is-bad-for-fileemailweb-servers/
- http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.5/Technical_Notes/Known_Issues-kernel.html
- http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5079940
- http://blog.jcole.us/2010/09/28/mysql-swap-insanity-and-the-numa-architecture/
- http://kevinclosson.wordpress.com/2009/05/14/you-buy-a-numa-system-oracle-says-disable-numa-what-gives-part-ii/
- http://www.pythian.com/news/1324/oracle-performance-issue-high-kernel-mode-cpu-usage/

Answer (score 0):

> time dd if=/dev/zero of=1000 bs=2M count=500 conv=fdatasync

...

> real    4m40.565s
>
> user    0m0.000s
>
> sys 4m40.521s

Well it's certainly got nothing to do with the fact you're normally running Oracle (NB, while /dev/zero will generate output quickly, writing lots of null bytes to a Unix filesystem is not a very good benchmark due to sparse file support - in this case performance is so bad that the problem is still evidenct though).

Even your 'normal' timings seem rather slow - but again there is a huge gulf between these and the poor performance.

On an oldish, 2 core single SATA box I get:

```
real    0m6.961s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m1.459s
```

Can you easily switch around your disk config (e.g. bypass the megaRAID controller and use mdadm (software) raid? (NB I've had some serious issues running MySQL on top of an md device previously - while that may have just been me / old bugs now fixed, I'd recommend planning for a worst-case outcome when testing this).

The occassional poor performance suggests that disk may be going off line then getting rebuilt - any errors being reported?

Comment: The megaraid tool not showing any errors. I prefer not touch the raid configuration for now since the OS is on it. I wonder what is the reason of 1 cpu core stuck on 100.0%sy.

Comment: also i want to add that the first indication of the problem is this situation when i see 1 cpu core stuck on 100%sy so i think the issue related somehow to the kernel

Comment: what are you talking about with sparse file support? writing out zeros has nothing to do with sparse files.

Comment: @Patrick: suggest you go do some background reading

Comment: @symcbean A sparse file when read back is presented as zeros. Writing zeros out does not create a sparse file. You have to seek to a position in the file which does not exist and then everything before that position is filled in as zeros even though you didnt actually write anything there.

Comment: @symcbean: agreed. Writing zeroes to a file doesn't make it sparse. You *do* need to `seek(2)`. Though I can see how it can be confusing because *reading* from the sparse portions of a file yields zeroes.